Can I re-use a hardware USB token for newer Code Signing Certificates when old expires?
I currently have a few expired Code Signing Certificates from Sectigo on their Safenet USB tokens for signing software.
I'm considering renewing + obtaining additional Code Signing Certificates for different projects and wondering if I can reuse the same USB token for those certificates. Also, it takes a quite long time to receive the new cert&token by mail.
Here are my specific questions:

Is it possible to store new certificate (from Sectigo or other providers) on the same USB token? Do I need to format the USB token first?

Are there any limitations in terms of token storage capacity or compatibility with different providers

Are there any specific tools or software I need to put a new certificate on an old token?



No, tokens can't be tampered with otherwise it would be no point in using them, don't you think?

Maybe new signing keys can be imported, maybe not. Maybe you can generate a private key on-device, then have it create a CSR. There’s no general rule. It is important to note that the certificate isn’t what’s doing the signature. It may not even be stored on the hardware device at all.

@ChanganAuto: That's a massive oversimplification. The point of tokens is not that you cannot tamper with them; the point is that you cannot extract keys from them. That's completely different from uploading new keys or deleting old ones, which most such tokens actually allow by default. The token issuer can change the management key, but many do not.

But there is an article how to re-initialize tokens? https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/how-to-initialize-or-reset-a-safenet-5110fips-usb-token-device-password

It's neither an exceptionally good nor an exceptionally bad idea, but you can simply reuse the existing key material for a new certificate. The key is, after all, still safe on the token.


Is it possible to store new certificate (from Sectigo or other providers) on the same USB token?

Depends on token and how the provider has configured it. Usually I would expect the token to remain fully writable, though the provider may have changed the "management key" for it, but I believe that's generally rare.
For example, the DigiCert website has an article about using a SafeNet eToken 5110 that it sells, where it explicitly says that the management key ("administrator password") is all-zeros and therefore the token can be used in any way you like.
Edit: The Security policy document for eToken 5110 seems to say that the "management key" is only needed to reformat a token (if the PIN is lost), or to perform some low-level firmware operations, but it is actually enough to have "Card Holder" access in order to store new data on an already-initialized token; i.e. the regular token password is enough.
[Side note: I actually use a 5110 that I've bought empty via eBay, as well as an older eToken 72K from a government issuer, and have never needed to specify the management key when adding keys to them – but so far I assumed that the PKCS#11 module automatically supplied the default one. But from reading the security policy doc, it seems like that's not really the case, or it only happens with --init-token at the most.]
This of course will differ between manufacturers – e.g. it seems to be the opposite from how YubiKey PIV operates (the management key is required for PIV updates) – and possibly even between models.

Do I need to format the USB token first?

Depends on token and how the provider has configured it. I'd generally expect that formatting would not be required as long as the management key is known, although tokens from different manufacturers may behave differently. (In the specific examples of Yubikeys or SafeNet eTokens, it is definitely not required as the tokens can hold multiple certificates at once.)

Are there any limitations in terms of token storage capacity

Yes, tokens store the entire certificate and key internally (unlike TPMs), so they usually have limits – either in terms of "slots" (e.g. Yubikey) or kilobytes (e.g. SafeNet).

In the specific case of YubiKey, its PIV smartcard mode was originally designed to emulate a DoD/military "CAC" card, and the GUI manager app only shows four slots which all have different behavior, but starting with Yubikey v4 those can be made general-purpose and there are ~20 of them.

On the other hand, a SafeNet eToken doesn't have predefined slots at all; its capacity is measured in kilobytes and depends entirely on what you upload. For example, the still-popular "eToken 5110" has 80 kilobytes of storage; an older "eToken PRO 64K" had, as its name says, 64 kB of storage.



or compatibility with different providers

Each token's firmware has support for specific algorithms only (since all signing has to happen within the token). For example, many tokens can handle RSA-2048 but not RSA-4096, and some can handle only those sizes but not intermediate sizes; the latter is always the case for EC cryptography, where only specific curves will be supported (e.g. P-256 but not Ed25519, and so on).
Many code signing CAs only support tokens which can provide an attestation that your private key was generated within the token, and not just imported from a file – e.g. Sectigo will only let you reuse a Yubikey but not any other token. (For the same reason they insist on tokens in the first place, i.e. so that they won't have to rush to revoke leaked certificates after customers' mistakes.)

Are there any specific tools or software I need to put a new certificate on an old token?

Typically it's available through the same tools or software that you'd need to use an existing certificate.

For example, if the token's software comes with a PKCS#11 module (Windows .dll or Linux .so) for integration with signing process, you can also use it to generate or upload new keys. (The Java-based Keystore Explorer might be useful.)

Similarly, if you install Windows drivers that make the token visible through CryptoAPI, you can also use the same CryptoAPI (e.g. through certutil or MMC) to generate a new private key and a certificate request – all you have to do is select the correct CSP or KSP to put the key in hardware. (Which, by the way, also has a KSP that lets you make TPM-protected certificates.)

Most tokens also come with their own (often Windows-only) software, e.g. "SafeNet Authentication Client" or "YubiKey Manager", which offers token-specific management features.



I have SafeNet Token,  but  SECTIGO sent me this information with it.
Does this mean I cannot re-use this Safenet token when I don't have admin pwd:
•The password you have is a token password, and you have three attempts to access the token. If you fail all three attempts, you must contact Sectigo Support to unlock the token
•The admin password for the code signing certificate is not accessible to you. Incorrect usage (5 attempts) can permanently lock the token, making it unusable.

@Tomas  "The admin password for the code signing certificate is not accessible to you"  But it IS accessible by Sectigo, if necessary, so this is not an absolute blocker.  From what I can tell, the token that Sectigo provide CAN be re-used, but their policies/tech doesn't allow that.

@Tomas: On second thought, after going through the "security policy" document for the eToken 5110, it seems that basic operations like generating a key pair or storing an object only need Card Holder authentication – i.e. the token password or PIN. So although you cannot reformat the token, you should be able to reuse it as long as you know the current PIN.
